# Connect p2p users without their ip addresses?

Tags: networking, p2p

Is it possible to create a p2p system - say for direct chat or file transfers - where the ip address is never exposed to the clients? I assume at the very least a third party server could handle IP address mapping or can even this be avoided somehow? The idea is to avoid a single point of failure, attack or censorship.

Comment: P2P implies that the users are connected to each other, that is their addresses must be known to each other. To hide their addresses you'd need some sort of intermediary (regardless if it's yours or provided by protocol). In other words, you cannot hide IPs and have P2P connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into using routing protocol such as [TOR](https://www.torproject.org), [I2P](http://www.i2p2.de) or [Freenet](https://freenetproject.org). These provide some anonymity by hiding the true source of the messages while also avoiding the single point of failure and/or attack vector of having a central server that all users connect to.

Note that throughput is often significantly lower than with direct connections, and latency is  usually several orders of magnitude longer (due to the packets being routed through several nodes in the network).

Comment: What if I only want to hide the IP address from the clients? What kind of server setup would that require?

Comment: To hide the IP you need to route all traffic through some other node, be it a trusted server or an untrusted peer, adding some sort of cryptographic verification. Note that a central server is the worst possible setup from the single point of failure point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Fact is: If the other peer doesn't see your IP, you must be tunneled, proxied, or whatever. There is no way for getting a direct connection and hiding your IP.